# retrieve the last record when grouping mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

i have table t_message, its collect conversation beetween user and user.

here's the table strcture.

```
 id_message sender_user_id receiver_user_id message 
1          2              1                test 1
2          1              2                test 2
3          2              1                test 3
4          1              2                test 4
```

with that table, i have an objective to collect group of conversation for user, and as example i want to colletct groups of conversation beetween user 1 and user 2. using this query

```
select * from ( select * from t_message where receiver_user_id = 1 order by id_message DESC ) group by sender
```

and the result is

```
id_message sender_user_id receiver_user_id message 
3          2              1                test 3
```

it's showing group of conversation beetwen user 1 and user 2, but not showing the conversation beetwen user 1 and user 2. its just showing the last conversation from user 2 or sender.

what query i need to collect a group of conversation beetwen user, and retrieve the last record of that conversation.
any suggestion?

oh by the way, i am very sory for my bad english, i hope you got the idea.

Comment: is the desire result record 4?

Comment: yeah, so the result i wanted is. group of conversation contain the last conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concat the sender and receiver to form a conversation

```
select a.id, a.conversation, b.sender_user_id, b.receiver_user_id, b.message
from (
  select max(id_message) id,
         if(sender_user_id>receiver_user_id,
            concat(receiver_user_id,',',sender_user_id),
            concat(sender_user_id,',',receiver_user_id)) conversation
  from t_message
  group by conversation) a
join t_message b on a.id = b.id_message;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11c19/5)